# efficient way to append a column to an array in Fortran?

Tags: fortran

Suppose I have an array `A(n,m)` and an array `B(n)`. I want to create an array `C(n,m+1)` where its first m columns are the columns in `A` and its last column is `B`

What is the best way of doing this in Fortran? By best I mean more efficient (less time consuming)

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
C(1:n,1:m) = A(1:n,1:m)
C(1:n,m+1) = B(1:n)
```